# How to EXPECT_CALL a specific version of a method?

Tags: googlemock

I have a class with 2 different versions of the same named method:

```
MOCK_METHOD0(CmdData, char*());
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(CmdData, const char*());
```

How do I set the EXPECT_CALL for each of them?

it seems to only set the call for the non-const version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Const()` argument wrapper:

```
MockClass foo;
EXPECT_CALL(foo, CmdData());         // Expectation for the non-const version
EXPECT_CALL(Const(foo), CmdData());  // Expectation for the const version
```

This is covered in the [Mocking Cookbook](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#SelectOverload) under the section "Selecting Between Overloaded Functions".

Comment: Since `testing::Const()` returns a const reference (just as [`std::as_const()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const)) it is also possible to define the mock as const if you do not need to expect calls to non-const overloads. However this is less verbose and more likely to break.